# Center inline content in a dynamic-width container that is too thin

Tags: html, css

Say I have an image, 260px wide. It's in a container that for whatever reason is only 200px wide. It will naturally show up like this:

[image: image in a container that is too thin and overflowing on the right edge]

A dashed border has been added to the container to make it visible, and the image has been made slightly transparent. As you can see, the image overflows out of the right of the container. But what could I do to get it like this?

[image: image in a container that is too thin and overflowing on both edges]

No matter how thin the container is, the image should overflow evenly from both sides, and stay centered. I require that the image do this no matter the width of the container, since it is dynamically sized.

The same should go for text, too:

[image: text overflowing incorrectly and correctly after that]

HTML and CSS only, please. Here's what I have.

*HTML*

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://cdn4.buysellads.net/uu/1/6167/1530364713-1527799204-pink_logo.png">
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="container">
    <p>
        This text is a little too long for the container
    </p>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
body {
    margin-left: 3em;
}

img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.container {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you want to fiddle with it: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/o3n0q67a/)

Clarifier: The most modern option is what I'm looking for, as long as it is supported by all browser versions with at least 1% market share as according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), with the exception of IE11.

Comment: _“HTML and CSS only, please.”_ - show what your research and own efforts have resulted in so far, please - instead of just ”dropping off your order.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS Flexbox! You can tell the container that it should center its content, which will result in overflowing of the content left and right. Then just hide the overflow and voila!

For text you also have to prevent it from breaking if you REALLY want it to overflow its container.

For an example, look at the snippet below.

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/260">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>This is really long text. It should not break and overflow its container left and right, for it is wider</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually explicitly _want_ to show the overflow, in my case.

Comment: @SpyderScript Well, in that case nothing easier than removing `overflow: hidden` and add `.container img {opacity: 0.5}`.

Comment: Great. It does seem that the image is being shrunk to fit the container, however. I think you need `flex-shrink: 0` on the image as well.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Apply `position: relative` to the container.

2.) Apply the following CSS to the image or content DIV:

```
#my_image {
  display: block;
  width: 260px; /* whatever value, but fixed width */
  height: 180px; /* whatever value, but fixed height */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

that's the standard method for horizontally and vertically centering an element inside another element, which also works if the container is smaller that the element itself.

Here is an example (note that I applied `overflow: hidden` to the container to hide the parts that go beyond the borders of the container):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#my_image {
  display: block;
  width: 260px;
  /* whatever value, but fixed width */
  height: 180px;
  /* whatever value, but fixed height */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" id="my_image">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a hack. Before flexbox, this was the standard way to horizontally *and* vertically center elements, and if you need to support older browsers, it still is...

Comment: Your requirements should say if this or the solution from Lioxo (flexbox) is the best answer. Do you support modern browsers only? Go for flexbox. If you go for all-browsers; this is your option. I would pick this one as many people/companys are not up-to-date.

Comment: We support all browser versions with at least 1% market share as according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) (with the exception of IE11). According to that, all browser versions that don't support flexbox have less than 1%, and so this compatibility option is not our first pick. I'll add a clause to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
   background-color: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   
}

.flex-container > img {
   opacity: 0.7;
   position: absolute;
   left: -25%;
   width: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img height="auto" src="https://picsum.photos/260">
</div>
```

Comment: The container can be any width, because it is dynamic. Your solution would only work if the container was exactly 200 wide and the image was exactly 250.

Comment: True. Without using JS ("HTML and CSS only, please") then it's exactly as you said. It's static.

Comment: Not necessarily. Using fluid CSS methods (percentages, flexbox, grid, etc.) makes elements dynamic, changing width and/or height depending on content and screen width.